# Unable to launch URL in edge browser (using replit platform)- Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, microsoft-edge, replit

I tried to use replit online platform for web scraping using selenium in Edge browser. replit automatically install selenium 4.1.3 but I couldn't find msedge-selenium-tools to support this version.
[image: selenium (3.141) Error]
How can I install selenium (3.141) to support msedge-selenium-tools?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You
Bibek

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this online IDE,  but I did some testing and found that it seems to be able to control the version of the referenced package via a configuration in the `pyproject.toml` file.

First, uninstall selenium 4.1.3 in installed Packages. When installing `edge-selenium-tools` package, you will find that it bundles `selenium 3.141` installed with edge-selenium-tools. Second, add this line in `pyproject.toml` file.

```
selenium = "^3.141.0"
```

Something like this:

[image]

In addition, for more questions related to IDE replit, I suggest you post your questions in [its community](https://replit.com/talk/ask), I think there may be someone with more relevant experience who can answer your questions.